# Ubuntu : apt-get install <package> equivalent in C++ apt-pkg library

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, apt

I am building a small QT (C++) application where I ask user the software he want to install. Once he selected some packages a, b, c from the list all I have to do is run

sudo apt-get install a b c

One way of doing this is using Qprocess or System and run this command directly from C++. But I thought this would be a hack and wanted to do using apt-pkg C++ library. But sadly documentation is very sparse for this library :( I saw source codes of some similar softwares - Software updater ( apt-watch ) etc and found it too complex. Just to run above command, it has lot of code - Initializing pkgCacheFile, PkgIterator, pkgAcqArchive.

Do I have to do all this to run this simple command ? Isn't there a direct function which takes software name as argument and install it ? Where Can I get a sample working code for the same ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably easier to just use QProcess.  That's basically what the Ubuntu GUI package front-end seemed to do last time I used it (a few years ago).

Comment: Have you looked into [QApt](http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/introducing-qapt-and-the-muon-package-manager/)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Packagekit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit).

Here's [a link](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-using.html) to its documentation page containing some examples